# How can i use AJAX to access any page on internet?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, http, web

I tried to use standard ajax method, to retrieve page content from an URL, however, if I'm not putting this `ajax.htm` on a server, e.g apache, and AJAX won't emit.

And if I place it in a http server, trying to access the Internet, it was canceled deliberately, here a screenshot from chromium:

[image]

That's weird? Just posting to a virtual machine (192.168.56.212) with AJAX.

P.S: Accessing localhost with AJAX works anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant. The browser will usually prohibit connections to any other domain than the one from which the page came. This is called the [`same origin policy`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). There is a way to get around this for some URLs called [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), but that only works for sites that use it.